# MySQL syntax error when searching from a View

Tags: mysql, syntax, ip

I would really appreciate if someone can help me here.

So I created a view "ip_range", it's basically an ip range, the columns are

**INET_ATON(ip) | (INET_ATON(ip)+(prefix))**

Now when I try to search for an entry in the view that lies between the two ranges, I keep getting an error. This is what I am typing in my query

```
 select * from ip_range WHERE "2624412513" BETWEEN INET_ATON(ip) AND (INET_ATON(ip)+(prefix);
```

I'm pretty sure it's a syntax error or something, but not sure.

sorry guys for not being more clear, I have the bracket in my query. When I run the query, **I get "Empty set (0.00 sec)** Even though I see that it lies in the range.

```
select * from ip_range WHERE "2624412513" BETWEEN 'INET_ATON(ip)' AND '(INET_ATON(ip)+(prefix))';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Here's the updated code,

Thank you.

Comment: There is a closing bracket missing at the end.

Answer (score 0):

you have missing brackets in the end

```
 select * from ip_range WHERE "2624412513" BETWEEN INET_ATON(ip) AND (INET_ATON(ip)+(prefix));
```

or try this

```
  select * from ip_range WHERE INET_ATON(ip) < 2624412513 
                          AND  INET_ATON(ip)+(prefix) > 2624412513
```

Comment: Im sorry for the mistake. I forgot to put the bracket at the end in my topic. But when I run the query, I get no results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am still not getting the right answer. When I use   select * from ip_range WHERE 'INET_ATON(ip)' <= 2624412513 limit 10; separately, I get a list, but that list is just about eveyrthing. So for somereason my greater to is not working.

Comment: then this function is not right , maybe its like that `INET_ATON(ip+prefix)` or ?